# What is the purpose of Chemistry?

Tags: kittens-game

The info box for the Chemistry upgrade just says "TBD".

[image: Chemistry Info]

Does this upgrade do anything?

Comment: Classic Arqade.

Comment: @troylatroy: I swear, some mad genius built this game specifically for the purpose of farming Arqade question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemistry is a very significant upgrade. The TBD refers to the flavour text, which it obviously is lacking because "TBD" stands for "to be determined".

Chemistry unlocks the crafting of alloy as well as:

> **Buildings**
>
> - Oil Well
> - Calciner
>
> **Upgrades**
>
> - Alloy Axe
> - Alloy Barn
> - Alloy Warehouses

[Source](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Technologies#Chemistry)